# Is it possible to retrieve the HostServices interface within Drombler FX?

Tags: java, javafx, osgi, javafx-8, drombler-fx

Is there some way to retrieve the HostServices implementation within a bundle? I would like to open a link within an action. Maybe putting it into the osgi service registry would be a good idea so people can access it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently it's not possible to retrieve the HostServices as the Application instance is not accessible from any JavaFX component (Node, Scene, Window,...) AFAIK and it's not handled specially by Drombler FX either.

Depending on your use case, a work-around could be to use the [Desktop](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Desktop.html) class, though this will create a dependency on the AWT stack for the time being.

I filed an [issue to support HostServices](https://github.com/Drombler/drombler-fx/issues/121) in Drombler FX.